# Silverlight developer runtime earlier versions

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I need this version of Silverlight developer runtime:
Silverlight_Developer.exe 4.0.60831

I tried to find it, but i was not successful.

Anybody can help me where I can find this version of Silverlight developer runtime?

Thanks advanced,

l.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you go](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18149) I am not sure about the exact version but this contains the SL 4 Developer runtime

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved my problem I found this:

Microsoft® Silverlight™ Release History

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=12121